# Sync Provider for SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework, azure-sql-database

I am looking for SQL Azure specific provider that seems to be published by Microsoft.

I downloaded the sync tool given at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bce4ad61-5b76-4101-8311-e928e7250b9a&displaylang=en but it contains a sync wizard. I need to implement a lot of custom synchronization logic to synchronize separate SQL server express databases with a single SQL Azure database.

Currently we are using the SQLsyncprovider, but looking to make the sync process more efficient if possible using sql azure providers. But I am not getting the provider itself (so that I can use it in my code). Does anyone know how to get that?

Also I already have a lot of sync logic written with sqlsyncprovider, so hoping that there is not much of rewriting involved in moving to sql azure provider :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider is definitely there as part of the download. It isn't added to the GAC, but you can browse to it. However, only an x86 version is available, so you won't be able to use it inside of your Azure project.

If you're writing a non-Azure application that connects into SQL Azure, you can use the x86 library and build your application as x86.

Comment: What do you mean? The link you posted yourself is the only thing available. Everything else is from experience.

Comment: I am accepting the answer because i do not see anything else - although this is far from perfect.

Comment: If you let me know what you're looking for, I might be able to help. As I see it, I've answered your question.